# PostgreSQL shutdown tracking

Tags: postgresql

PG shutdowns are taking time.
I am using the "smart" shutdown process by sending SIGINT signal to the PG process. So, it waits for the child processes to die gracefully before exiting. Can I somehow know what is the child process kill where it is stuck/taking time?

I cannot find a documentation on what steps are included in a "smart" shutdown. I am guessing we take checkpoints and wait for WAL writers and archivers to finish. I want to track how much time each of these is taking to finish its task and exit.

Comment: " Can I somehow know what is the child process kill where it is stuck/taking time"  I can't understand this sentence.  Did "kill" just show up uninvited?

Answer (score 0):

There are only two things that normally can take a long time during a smart shutdown: waiting until all client connections have disconnected on their own, and then the shutdown checkpoint.

To monitor the latter, set `log_checkpoints = on`. The former can take forever – you are at the mercy of the client application. For that reason, it is usually smarter to use the default "fast" shutdown mode that forcibly disconnects the clients.